# Wildfly 9.0.2-Final ClassNotFoundException for Struts 1.x

Tags: java, jboss, struts, struts-1

While deploying `app.war` (**Struts 1.x**) on my **Wildfly** this information appears:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to
>   process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"app.war\" Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective
>   information for class org.ajaxtags.tags.AjaxDisplayTag with
>   ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.app.war:main\"
>   from Service Module Loader Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   au/id/jericho/lib/html/Segment Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.id.jericho.lib.html.Segment from
>   [Module \"deployment.app.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

I have downloaded `jericho-html-2.6.1-sources.jar` and placed this as a module into `${wf-dir}\modules\system\layers\base\au\id\jericho\lib\html\main\` with an `module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="au.id.jericho.lib.html">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jericho-html-2.6.1-sources.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And there's still same issue...
Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by changing build system from Ant to Maven - looks like Wildfly has some problem while resolving directory conventions. On Glassfish 3.1.1 this worked with Ant